# Composer branch against Stash

Tags: git, composer-php, branch

I have the most simplest composer.json file and I try to pull in a branch (mybranch) of my private repo that resides in Stash (not GitHub).

```
{
  "config": {
  "vendor-dir": "lib"
},
  "name": "company/framework",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "ssh://git@stash.server.private:7999/lt/php-ga.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
  "company/php-ga": "dev-mybranch"
  }
}
```

Apparently, you say `dev-<branch>`, to tell composer it should pull the branch, but when I run `composer update`, I always get:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package getbutik/php-ga dev-mybranch exists as getbutik/php-ga[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Which constraints is this message talking about?

Comment: is your `mybranch` pushed to the repository in stash and publicly available? the error message tells you that composer only finds the `master` branch

Comment: Yes it is pushed and available